# Automate the action of "button press" after a certain order status in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hello beautiful people,

I'm creating invoices via a custom plugin that doesn't send them automatically to customers after orders are marked as completed, there is a button for that.

Order preview with generate invoice button. 
[image: Order preview with generate invoice button.]

How can I make it so that when any order is marked as completed that button gets pressed automatically?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I think the best way of doing is using a hook

function run_the_function( $order_id ) {
    //code to trigger generate invoice comes here
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'run_the_function, 10, 1 );

Comment: Hi Ram, yes, thank you! One of the first things that popped up in my mind would be something that would go in functions.php. Your suggestion is exactly what I was looking for.